# Cocoapods installation takes ages. Is there something wrong?

Tags: ios, git, cocoapods

I've a small project with CocoaPods, and it's taking ages to install...

```
pod update --verbose
Update all pods
  Preparing

Analyzing dependencies

Updating spec repositories
  $ /usr/bin/git rev-parse  >/dev/null 2>&1
Updating spec repo `master`
  $ /usr/bin/git pull --ff-only
```

This is the Podfile. Am I doing something wrong?

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'

pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'
pod 'ARAnalytics', '~> 2.7'
```

Comment: Not sure why either, Cocoapods seems to be slower for me compared to NPM for Nodejs. Have you tried Carthage, apparently it's a lightweight package manager, not sure if it's any faster than Cocoapods:  https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a blatant network problem.